# CSS after before property not work?

Tags: css

here i am using after and before tag in css.
And this is my div.
I don't know why my after not working.
Everything work fine but my after and before not work properly.
I want that my div show over before line.
please help me what should i do to resolve this.

my code

```css
div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section {
        margin: auto;
        width: 900px;
        z-index: 100;
        border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
        min-height:250px;
        background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 55px;
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
        -webkit-animation: fadein 2s
        -moz-animation: fadein 2s; 
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
        -o-animation: fadein 2s; 
        animation: fadein 2s;
    }
    div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::before
    {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: .2rem;
        background: #dcdcdc;
    }
    div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::after
    {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: .2rem;
        background: #red;
    }
```

```html
<div type="timeline/slideshow">
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title </header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title </header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title </header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
 <section class='sectionDiv'>
  <header>Title </header>
  <article>Content</article>
 </section>
</div>
```

[image]

.

Comment: negative z-index on before/after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. I've added a fixed height (equals to the bottom margin), removed top style, and updated bottom style. Also applied the css to section::after.

https://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/yKXQNw?editors=1100

```
div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section::after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -55px;
    width: .2rem;
    background: red;
    height: 55px;
}
```